# TransactionScope rolling back in a wrong order

Tags: c#, transactions, rollback

I use the `TransactionScope` class in my application because I need to do some operations trnsactionally, naturally (either all of them succeeds or none).

Since this operations are not only database related, I defined my own transactional behaviour for disc and system services operations (such as transactional file moving and service stoppping) by implementing the `IEnlistmentNotification` interface. It works fine, no doubt in that, but when I put all this things together in one application, I got unexpected results.

Imagine the following situation

```
using(var ts = ...)
{
    TxServiceManager.StopServices(services);
    TxFileManager.MoveFiles(files);
    DbManager.RunChangeScripts(scripts);
    TxServiceManager.StartServices(services);
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Worked pretty good until I got to a situation which required rolling back all operations. It happends when starting services and I would imagine, that the transaction scope will

1. stop services it managed to start
2. roll back a database
3. restore files
4. start services

But gues what? It simly starts with the first operation in the code listing, which is services stopping that of course rolls back by starting the services. All right, services are running and then it fails on the second operation, because I cannot overwrite files used by these services when they are running.

How it comes that rollback starts with the first operation and not with the last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because simply (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx)):

> You should be aware that notifications might not be sent sequentially, or in a particular order.

The order is not defined.

Comment: Ah, thank you Marc. So, what would you advise me to do if I need to roll back in a specified and the most natural way (which is in the opposite order of the executing)?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek well, I suspect the `IEnlistmentNotification` API assumes that different resources are *independent*, hence the behavior. If that isn't the case... tricky - unless your code explicitly introduces the chaining into the code, which would be ugly and messy. I don't have an immediate answer for you here, other  than that `IEnlistmentNotification` *by itself* probably isn't "it"

Comment: Ok, let's wait a while if someone could provide any sensible solution.